# How can I make my nginx web server reachable from outside its local network?

Tags: nginx, firewall, web-server, ping, curl

I am trying to reach a subdomain of my website from **outside** its local network.

I can successfully ping it (`ping my.subdomain.com`):

```
PING my.subdomain.com (ser.ver.ip.add) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from static.143.220.55.162.clients.your-server.de (ser.ver.ip.add): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=14.8 ms
64 bytes from static.143.220.55.162.clients.your-server.de (ser.ver.ip.add): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from static.143.220.55.162.clients.your-server.de (ser.ver.ip.add): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from static.143.220.55.162.clients.your-server.de (ser.ver.ip.add): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from static.143.220.55.162.clients.your-server.de (ser.ver.ip.add): icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from static.143.220.55.162.clients.your-server.de (ser.ver.ip.add): icmp_seq=6 ttl=53 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from static.143.220.55.162.clients.your-server.de (ser.ver.ip.add): icmp_seq=7 ttl=53 time=15.5 ms
^C
--- my.subdomain.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.833/15.263/15.577/0.243 ms
```

but it cannot successfully curl it (`curl -m 5 my.subdomain.com`):

```
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds
```

From **within** the host server, the curl (`curl -m 5 my.subdomain.com`) response is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of `sudo ufw status` is

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       ser.ver.ip.add            
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The output of `netstat -tulnp` is

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      80509/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      724/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      797/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      102144/registry     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      80509/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      797/sshd: /usr/sbin 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           724/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 ser.ver.ip.add:68       0.0.0.0:*                           722/systemd-network
```

What does this mean and how can I make the nginx web server reachable from outside?

Comment: A timeout usually indicates a firewall issue.

Comment: but `ufw status` says port 80 is allowing connections from Anywhere. What could be the issue specifically?

Comment: Most probably another firewall in front of the server

Comment: It's not clear to me how your setup is. What is your local network? Is your server behind some firewall? NAT?

Comment: @vidarlo How do I find out these two things? Sorry, I'm a real beginner

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Is it also possible that my nginx config is just wrong somehow? I mean something in `etc/nginx/*

Answer (score 0):

@Gerald Schneider was correct, it was another firewall in front of the server that needed to be configured to allow inbound connections on port 80